# Sporadic error when loading PHP extension in Azure App Service

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure App Service that makes use of the Redis PHP extension. Both the App Service and extension are PHP 5.6 / 32-bit. We are loading the PHP extension from a `settings.ini` in accordance with the [Azure documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime).

```
extension = "d:\home\site\wwwroot\ext\php_redis.dll"
```

*Once every few weeks* the App Service will fail to load the extension and the site breaks. We receive the following error in our logs:

> [06-Nov-2016 17:25:42 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'd:\home\site\wwwroot\ext\php_redis.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>   in Unknown on line 0

*This problem will go away on its own* some hours later, presumably when the app service restarts or is migrated to another VM. We have an identical 'secondary' app service in a different region that never exhibits this problem.

Has anyone seen this sporadic failure? How can it be prevented?

Comment: I had this before with the mbcrypt module in a Codeigniter application I was running on Azure. I raised a support ticket as it was only happening in North Europe and the issue was resolved within a couple of hours however I don't know what the resolution was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message which can be caused in some unexpected condition that the file path is formed properly, for example, when there is file storage failover, auto-healing, etc. 
We had tested installing `php_redis.dll` from application settings instead of `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR`, this way `php.ini` will be modified to include the extension path. This change can mitigate the issue.

Comment: To elaborate: The guidance we received was to specify the extension using the custom App Setting, `PHP_EXTENSIONS` = `d:\home\site\wwwroot\ext\php_redis.dll`. This strategy is also described in the Azure documentation and the (excellent)  Azure support folks indicated that it's considered the best practice.